# Import pyarmor obfuscated code using importlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyarmor

Suppose I have 2 modules - one has been obfuscated by PyArmor. The other imports the obfuscated module and uses it:

```
# obfuscated.py
def run_task(conn):
    conn.send_msg("Here you go")
    print(conn.some_val + 55)
    return 0
```

```
# Non obfuscated (user) code
import importlib.util


class conn:
    some_val = 5
    
    def send_msg(msg):
        print(msg)

def main():
    # import obfuscated # This works...but I need to dynamically load it:

    # This does not:
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", r'c:\Users\me\obfuscated.py')
    obfuscated = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(swdl)
    ret = obfuscated.run_task(conn)
    print("from main: ", ret)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I import the obfuscated file using `import` it is fine. But I need to use `importlib` to dynamically import the obfuscated file. The importlib does not work - I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'module.name' has no attribute 'obfuscated'
```

The idea is that the user can write a script using the API available within `obfuscated.py` but need to load the module from wherever it resides on their system.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a method based on what I read here: https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mode.html#restrict-mode

I use a proxy between the user code and the obfuscated code.

- User code may or may not be obfuscated
- The obfuscated code is obviously obfuscated!
- The proxy must not be obfuscated (for simplicity, I obfuscated everything then copied the original `proxy.py` over the obfuscated one)

So, now user code imports the `proxy.py` using `importlib` instead of the `obfuscated.py`.

And the proxy merely imports the `obfuscated.py`:

```
# proxy.py
import obfuscated
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to import modules dynamically in this way:

```py
    code = open('c:\Users\me\obfuscated.py','r').read()
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(package_name,loader=None)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    module.__file__ = 'c:\Users\me\obfuscated.py'
    globals_dict = {"__file__":module.__file__}
    exec(code, globals_dict)
    for item in [x for x in globals_dict["__builtins__"] if not x.startswith("_")]:
        setattr(module,item,globals_dict["__builtins__"].get(item))
```

It reads code from a file, initiates a module, and eventually puts variables in a dictionary. You can find the module's functions in `globals_dict["__builtins__"]`